# next-auth middleware not evaluating JS correctly

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am encountering a strange behavior in the next-auth middleware.js file:

The following code works:

```
export {default} from 'next-auth/middleware'

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/dashboard'],
    pages: {
        signIn: 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/login',
        error: '/api/auth/error',
    },
}
```

...while the following does not (redirects every route to */api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=%2F*):

```
export {default} from 'next-auth/middleware'

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/dashboard'],
    pages: {
        signIn: 'http://localhost:8000' + '/accounts/login', // <== NOTICE THE STRING CONCATENATION HERE
        error: '/api/auth/error',
    },
}
```

I am on `next@13.4` and `next-auth^4.20.1`.

Does anybody know what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `Next` webpack configuration is resolving the `pages` fields to your actual pages when it is a constant string, but when concatenated it cannot be resolved at compile time.

[According to the Next documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#pages), the `pages` field should not contain a host part:

> This should match the pages configuration that's found in [...nextauth].ts.

and [further here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages):

> When using this configuration, ensure that these pages actually exist. For example error: '/auth/error' refers to a page file at pages/auth/error.js

```js
pages: {
  signIn: '/api/auth/signin',
  error: '/api/auth/error',
}
```

Comment: I am including the host because I am performing OIDC login with a Provider which runs on a different host... but at least you gave me something to think about (webpack...)

Comment: @mettjus Are you using `Providers.IdentityServer4`? I'm not that familiar but it looks like you can set the URL directly there in `[...nextauth].js`

Comment: No, I am trying to define a custom OAuth provider (OIDC). I'm diving deeper into the docs to figure out how to configure it properly (ie: have the `signIn` function to work properly)

Comment: It looks like `IdentityServer4` is equivalent to OIDC v1 https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/b96f01319c751c7d62433c24fdb9f3f8f1e572c1/packages/core/src/providers/identity-server4.ts#L40-L41 but from your `signin` page you could also just do a manual redirect to an arbitrary external URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the encoding issue. Try this

- `new URL(url, [base])`

  ```
  new URL('/accounts/login','http://localhost:8000' )
  ```